# Chamberlain and Angrist Newey test for fixed effect panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, identification, systemfit

I'm trying to reproduce the estimations of table 7.1 in Baltagi (2013) Econometric Analysis of Panel Data (5th edition), page 133. Also, I would to reproduce the Chamberlain (1982) or its Angrist-Newey (1991) equivalence test of the working paper of Baltagi, Bresson & Pirotte (2009) *Testing Fixed-effects restrictions? A Monte Carlo study....* because Baltagi et al. say that is not common in applied research but it is very important to check the conditions for fixed effect models. (Please, find the data, the relevant papers and an R script with the estimations) in https://github.com/Joseperles/Statistical-questions/tree/master/Baltagi

I have got success to replicate all estimations with R's `plm` package. But I do not find any R Package or any R code to replicate both tests of restrictions. In the Angrist-Newey paper they use 3SLS estimations using SAS to perform their test.

I have seen that the R package `systemfit` performs 3SLS, but it seems that is not useful to estimate panel data models.

So, somebody knows any package or has any code to perform these unusual tests?

Comment: I have performed this solution in R.  The code is weird, but is written with the aim to show the step-by-step process and check the intermediate results.

If someone is interested in this topic, the data and my code could be downloaded from 

https://github.com/Joseperles/Statistical-questions/tree/master/Baltagi/My%20solution

Please, be sure that any error is mine. I would be grateful for suggestions, improvements and corrections.

Thanks a lot for your attention and best regards

José Perles
University of Alicante

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/558575/usage-of-panel-fixed-effects-specification-tests-by-chamberlain-1982-and-angri

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I myself find these nice functions `piest` and `aneweytest` in the R package `plm` of Prof. Yves Croissant for the Chamberlain test and the Angrist/Newey test, respectively.